# jQuery.getJSON REST access data

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, rest

Upon this json rest object:

```
[{"id_film":1,"title":"Forrest Gump","director":"Zameckis","year":"1994","price":"12.00","format":"DVD"},{"id_film":4,"title":"Back to the Future II","director":"Zameckis","year":"1989","price":"9.95","format":"DVD"}]
```

I am trying to build a response in a web page using the $getJSON function and place the response in a div id="films", but I do not know how to get to the 'title' and 'director' json properties.

```
$.getJSON( "http://rest/url", function( data ) {
    var items = [];
    $.each( data, function( title, director ) {
    items.push( "<li id='" + title + "'>" + director + "</li>" );
    });

    $( "<ul/>", {
        "class": "my-new-list",
         html: items.join( "" )
         }).appendTo( "#films" );
   });
```

In the response only appears an unordered list of:

```
[object Object]
[object Object]
```

What I could do to get a list of 'title' and 'director' unordered list?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
$.each( data, function( index, value ) {
    items.push( "<li id='" + value.title + "'>" + value.director + "</li>" );
});
```

[`each`](https://api.jquery.com/each/) callback expects two arguments `index`, `element`. Variable `director` contains *full* object so you get `[object Object]` (returns from `.toString()`, because you try convert object to `String`), you need get `property` from object, you can do it like in my example